# Android studio - Admob interstitial ads integration causes the app to crash

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial, smartbanner

Hi guys i integrated the admob banner ad in my mainactivity and works just fine but when i try to add the admob interstitial it causes the app to crash right when you open it no errors are shown when building the apk 
what ami doing wrong

im just a beginner in java coding so im not that much familiar with the envirement 
help a friend out

```
 package this.atest.packagename.myapplication;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
// Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
        Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewBanner);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



    }


    public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can post your crash log (also filter the adb log to show "ads").

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in your Manifest?

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just check it out in your xml file Should be

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And

```
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this

```
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.intertitial));
```

sometimes getstring not fetch so this is helpful.